# Controller layer and 3-tier architecture

Tags: architecture, asp.net

What is controller layer and where we put this in our 3-tier architecture?

```
1)UI
2)Business Logic Layer
3)Data Access Layer
```

I search in net but unable to get exact ans.Any links or sample example helps to understand better.Thanks.

Comment: I am not using mvc just simple asp.net web site so i want to know how I use controller layer  in 3-tier architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller layer is at the UI. It is basically "controlling" what action should take place in your application. Since you tagged this with `asp.net`, you should consider looking at Microsoft's version of this structure (called `MVC` for `Model`, `View`, `Controller`) - [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

Edit: Seeing your comment, I've never attempted to shoe-horn MVC into the old WebForms way of life, but it looks like others have - [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36898/Model-View-Controller-using-ASP-NET-WebForms-View)

Answer (score 0):

The controller handles user input. It is how the user controls your application. It's usually part of MVC: Model (data), View (screen), Controller (input device). The whole of MVC lives in the UI layer, with the model being passed around to the business and data layers (often after having been mapped to another entity).